# NameError in database query

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, nameerror

I'm using Python/Flask/SQLAlchemy with a PostgreSQL database. I'm calling a page to check search results, but it shows a NameError, that name is not defined. Name is the database column in the Foods table. The model for Foods is loaded.

```
@app.route('/_search_food')
    def search_food():
    search = request.args.get('search')
    results = Foods.query.filter(name.like('%' + search + '%')).all()
    return jsonify(results)
```

So I assume the problem is that it doesn't recognise name.like as searching in the right column?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your post!

Comment: how do you initialize name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the model class before the column in your filter:

```
Foods.name.like...

@app.route('/_search_food')
    def search_food():
    search = request.args.get('search')
    results = Foods.query.filter(Foods.name.like('%' + search + '%')).all()
    return jsonify(results)
```

Comment: Clear, thanks! Now I have another

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Will research that one now :)

Comment: Then you can accept the answer to close the question and then open a new one with the new error.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using 'contains' assuming you are willing to change the code.
The code then  would be something like:

```
Foods.objects.filter(name__icontains=search)
```

icontains will do case insensitive search.